# node.js doesn't seem to recognize sql.connection in some certain situation

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am very new to node.js and am now trying to build a connection using node.js to a MSSQL database. When the codes are being simpler say something like this:

```
var sql = require("mssql");

const pool = sql.connect('mssql://username:password@localhost/database')
```

The console doesn't give me any warning or errors on running the line for connection. I thought that means I'm good so I tried some other things but it says `TypeError: sql.Conection is not a constructor` when I was trying on this:

```
var dbConfig = {
server: "localhost\\server",
database: "database",
user: "user",
password: "password",
port: 1433
};

function getEmp() {
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
//Some other codes...
}
```

And if I try to remove the `new` over there it says `TypeError: sql.Conection is not a function` on the console.

This makes me feel like it suddenly not recognizing the sql but I was not getting such an error with the simple version of the code.

So my question is what was wrong with the code and if it did work in the first code and how to make the second code work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be doing `var conn = sql.connect(dbConfig)`. See the module's [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#callbacks) for more information.

Comment: When I tried your method out I get some other errors in the later lines of my code. But I assume you're right as I'm still very confused with node.js.
I found another way to solve it, and that would be sticking with what the codes meant to do, please check my answer out. :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is the problem on the syntax on `sql.Connection(dbConfig)`. With the help of someone else, he found that the contractor of the `sql` module has changed to `ConnectionPool`.

So, after changing the syntax to the correct one, things went smooth (except I got into trouble for having some stupid name for a SQL table, but that's solved and also not quite related to this question) and problem solved.

Thank you for your time.